# IOS: How to detect make/model of paired Bluetooth 3.0 device?

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, eaaccessory

IOS noob question here, though I hope its not a repetition.
Developing on XCode 4.3 targeting IOS 4+.
I am struggling with finding guidance on how to get a list of paired Bluetooth devices. Seems like there are multiple bluetooth interfaces but for dedicated purposes. Please correct me if I got the following wrong:
CoreBluetooth: Bluetooth LE (Bluetooth 4.0)
Gamekit: peer-peer based on session id
EAAccessory: MFi Bluetooth devices
There seems also to have been a defunct "BlueToothManager" API in XCode 3.0. Can someone share with me how to get a list of BlueTooth devices currently paired with the device running my app? I am only interested in make, model, identifier (or serial number). I dont actually need to communicate with the devices, just to be sure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try download this examples and get your need solves:

[CoreBluetooth-Demo](https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/CoreBluetooth-Demo) Link doesn't work. Links to github 404

[Appcelerator-iPhone-Bluetooth-Module](https://github.com/smontgomerie/Appcelerator-iPhone-Bluetooth-Module)

[proximity](https://github.com/revned/proximity)

[bluewoki](https://github.com/akosmasoftware/bluewoki)

[Titanium-Bluetooth-Module](https://github.com/euforic/Titanium-Bluetooth-Module)

Hope will be a helpful

Comment: thanks for the helpful hints. I tried all these samples. CoreBluetooth-Demo is applicable only to BTLE devices. Appcelerator-iPhone-Bluetooth-Module and Titanium-Bluetooth-Module are both not usable in Xcode. Proximity would've been excellent but IOBluetoothDevice API is only usable on OS X. Bluewoki is based on Gamekit API, dedicated to apps built with same appID.